# Maints sens de « à charge »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Pour connaître plus d'acceptions de « à charge », j'ai trouvé plusieurs sources et j'ai fait [une requête](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/forumtitles/a+charge) sur Wordreference. Je m'aperçois qu'il y a tant d'acceptions. L'entrée [*charge*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/charge?) du TLF en contient à foison et il est vraisemblable que liste n'est pas complète. Pourrait-on les détailler ? Existe-t-il de meilleurs renseignements ? Par exemple, [instruire à charge](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2160698), [à charge = une accusation](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=754983) ne sont pas révélées par les dicos :

1. à (la) charge (pour quelqu'un) de/que = à condition de/que ([Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/charge))  ([Larousse](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/charge/14743/locution?q=charge#152353))
2. Avoir quelqu'un à charge, à sa charge = subvenir à ses besoins.
3. Être à la charge de quelqu'un, d'un groupe, d'une institution = vivre à leurs frais ; en parlant d'une dépense, devoir être payée par eux :
4. Revenir à la charge = faire une nouvelle tentative, une nouvelle démarche après un ou plusieurs échecs ; insister.
5. Témoin à charge = témoin dont les déclarations étayent l'accusation.

Comment: L'article [*charge*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/charge) du wiktonnaire fait à mon avis le tour de tous les sens de ce mot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le problème ici est lié à la forte polysémie du mot *charge*. Il n'y a donc rien de surprenant à ce que ces expressions aient des sens très différents.

L'emploi 1 semble très daté en dehors du contexte légal (si elle s'emploie en contexte non légal). Au Québec, il m'est inconnu en dehors de l'expression *à charge de revanche* ("à condition qu'un service soit rendu en échange dans le futur"). *Charge* y a le sens de "tâche, devoir" (par extension du sens de "ce qui est chargé sur, bât").

Les sens 2 et 3 sont l'inverse l'un de l'autre (et ce ne devrait pas être difficile à deviner, très franchement). C'est le même sens de *charge* qui se retrouve ici.

Le sens 4 est l'extension métaphorique d'un sens différent de *charge*, le sens militaire "attaque, assaut".

Dans *témoin à charge*, la "charge" est l'*accusation* (d'où l'anglais *charges*, beaucoup plus commun). Même si la construction est inhabituelle et le sens de "charge" maintenant rare, ce n'est pas une expression particulièrement obscure.